# Subset of data frame by a data frame of indexes

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I'd like to select specific values of the following data frame:

```
src:
   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6
rA  9 12 44 88 11  1
rB 12  7 14 24 48 67
rC  0 15 97 17 13 18
rD 74 51 10 11 14  8
```

by indexes stored in a data frame with identical column names and row names as values:

```
idx:
   c1 c4 c6
 1 rA rD rA
 2 rD rA rB
 3 rB rC rC
```

So the result shall be like this:

```
res:
    1  2  3
 1  9 11  1
 2 74 88 67
 3 12 17 18
```

What would be the most elegant way to do so, please?

Comment: Why has the question received negative rating? I'd appreciate a feedback in form of a comment so that I can improve the question or prevent the same mistake(s) in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Please consider providing reproducible examples using `dput`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given original frames are defined like that:

```
src <- data.frame(matrix(c(9, 12, 44, 88, 11, 1,
                           12, 7, 14, 24, 48, 67,
                           0, 15, 97, 17, 13, 18,
                           74, 51, 10, 11, 14, 8), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE))
rownames(src) <- paste0("r", LETTERS[1:4])
colnames(src) <- paste0("c", 1:6)

idx <- data.frame(matrix(c("rA", "rD", "rB",
                           "rD", "rA", "rC",
                            "rA", "rB", "rC"), nrow = 3),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(idx) <- c("c1", "c4", "c6")
```

It can be solved with `sapply`:

```
sapply(colnames(idx), function(col) {
  src[idx[, col], col]
})
```

It produces a matrix with intended results:

```
     c1 c4 c6
[1,]  9 11  1
[2,] 74 88 67
[3,] 12 17 18
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `match` :

```
result <- idx
result[] <- src[cbind(match(unlist(idx), rownames(src)), 
                      match(names(idx)[col(idx)], names(src)))]
result

#  c1 c4 c6
#1  9 11  1
#2 74 88 67
#3 12 17 18
```

The logic here is to create a matrix with two columns first with row number and second with column number to extract data from.